# error in creating dummy variables for each continuous variable in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, dummy-variable, hmisc

I have a dataset which has 10 columns and these are continuous data. A sample of the same is collected through dput() and shon below:

```
structure(list(x1 = c(12.800454545, 17.71, 5.805, 13.111875, 14.121428571, 12.800454545, 17.71, 5.805, 13.111875, 14.121428571), 
x2 = c(281.61, 230.23, 11.61, 209.79, 296.55, 281.61, 230.23, 11.61, 209.79, 296.55), 
x3 = c(19.41, 13.91, 0, 2.37, 23.49, 19.41, 13.91, 0, 2.37, 23.49), 
x4 = c(65L, 62L, 3L, 41L, 45L, 65L, 62L, 3L, 41L, 45L), 
x5 = c(0.571428571, 1.857142857, 21.14285714, 2.571428571, 1.428571429, 0.571428571, 1.857142857, 21.14285714, 2.571428571, 1.428571429), 
x6 = c(52L, 40L, 3L, 22L, 33L, 52L, 40L, 3L, 22L, 33L), 
x7 = c(44.53, 15.38, 5.97, 4.97, 13.94, 44.53, 15.38, 5.97, 4.97, 13.94), 
x8 = c(65L, 53L, 3L, 41L, 45L, 65L, 53L, 3L, 41L, 45L), 
x9 = c(6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
x10 = c(46.43, 17.52, 0, 11.73, 0, 46.43, 17.52, 0, 11.73, 0)), 
row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to do is to write an automated function which would cut each variable into 5 groups using quantiles and create dummies and addback into dataset as columns.

I was trying to do something like this, but not able to do it:

```
create a copy of dataframe to work on dummy vars creations
d1 <- df

library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
for (i in 1:length(d1)){
  #print(table(cut2(d1[,i], g=5)))
  aa <- NULL
  bb <- NULL

  x1 <- select(d1, i)
  aa <- cut2(x1, g=5)

  # Create dummy variables
  bb <- model.matrix(~ aa + 0, data=df)
  colnames(bb) <- gsub("aa","",colnames(bb))     #clean column names
  bb <- as.data.frame(bb)   # convert matrix to dataframe


}
```

Comment: please fix: `cut2(, g=5)` thats already wrong. `aa <- NULL` and `bb <- NULL` is not necessary.

Comment: thanks, i missed it while typing and just updated the code. actually, I am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

If by dummy you mean the quantile rank of your observation, a solution can be :

```
for (i in 1:length(df)){
                        d1[,i] <- as.integer(cut2(df[,i], g=5)) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, What this function is doing, is creating quantile rank and replacing values in the column with the ranks. I needed to create new columns (dummies) say x1_d1, x1_d2, x1_d3 and so forth and each of these cols to have either 0 or 1 depending on the ranks within the original column x1. I guess, I could use "assign()" function there to do so.